# Check if post of title already exists

Tags: php, database, mysql

I'm writing a plugin that takes an xml feed and posts it into WordPress using wp-cron

Everything is working dandy, except it keeps adding the same posts over again.

So, I'm working on a system to check to see if a post of that title already exists.

I've written this, but its always returning 'already exists'

```
global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_title = %s', $article->heading);
        $wpdb->query( $query );

        if ( $wpdb->num_rows ) {
            error_log('already exists');
        } else {                
            wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);
        }
```

I'm fairly new to working with the database side of WordPress and I saw the `$wpdb` when googling for help. Now, I haven't defined this anywhere but the place I was reading seemed to suggest it was built in.

All help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Ever heard of the [XML_RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) API?

Comment: I originally started this task with XML_RPC but my manager has asked me to instead develop it as a plugin so he can re-use/sell it

Comment: And why can't he do that with XML_RPC?? At least it's an API. And why would you want to sell something that doesn't align with the product that its built upon?

Comment: Yes your right, but there were other reasons it was a bit easier this way was because i also have to convert the category names given in this feed to category ID's relative to the wordpress categories, which was looking to be a bit of a pain externally

Comment: There is one WordPress plugin [Duplicate Title Checker](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-title-checker/) which provides alert message that post title is unique or duplicate while entering new post. The answer given by "s_ha_dum" is correct but I am posting here because it may be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) is built in and is loaded by the WordPress Core on every page load.

I don't see any critical problem with your code. I am going to suggest some improvements because I see some places where could go wrong, but mostly that should work. That makes me think that `$article->heading` is not matching up to the inserted `post_title`. So...

Try to normalize your title with [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) which is how WordPress builds the post slug, and then check for that slug instead.

```
global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_name = %s', sanitize_title_with_dashes($article->heading));
        $cID = $wpdb->get_var( $query );
```

Now your query is looking for `post_name`, which is the slug or permalink tail, and I changed `$wpdb->query` to `$wpdb->get_var` since you are looking for a single variable, which we save to `$cID`.

Use a better check for your conditional.

`if ( !empty($cID) ) {`

However, this might not be the right approach at all. Look into the XML_RPC API mentioned by @kaiser. It has [post insertion capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost).

Comment: Now using what you suggested, but again it just keeps re-adding, a bigger overview available: http://pastebin.com/5TAHC3XU

Comment: Add [`wp_die($cID);`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) after your query, or log it some other way. Are you getting an ID? Also, what is the point of this: ` $allPosts = get_posts($opts);`? You aren't using `$allPosts` at all.

Comment: $cID printed out a number that was increcementing by 1 after each iteration, also good spot removed that now was for something I was trying, thank you

Comment: Argh... my switch is backwards. It should be `!empty($cID)` then do nothing.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman, many many thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php post_exists( "post_name" ); ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/